# Add string resources instead of static data

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add some string resources to replace Content string but i cannot seem to access them because its a static class. How do i add items to DummyItem from a non static context?

I edited to add a custom context class i seen on another post.
It works now but the custom context class throws a warning - Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak.

Is this actually a memory leak? How? and can i resolve it?

// Custom Context Class

```
public class MyCustomContext extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyCustomContext.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyCustomContext.context;
    }
}
```

// Dummy Content Class

```
public class DummyContent {

    public static final List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<>();

    public static final Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<>(5);

    static {
        addItem(new DummyItem("1", R.drawable.p1, "Item #1", "Author A", res.MyCustomContext.getAppContext().getString(R.string.ContentA));
        addItem(new DummyItem("2", R.drawable.p2, "Item #2", "Author B", res.MyCustomContext.getAppContext().getString(R.string.ContentB));
        addItem(new DummyItem("3", R.drawable.p3, "Item #3", "Author C", res.MyCustomContext.getAppContext().getString(R.string.ContentC)));
    }

    private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }

    public static class DummyItem {
        public final String id;
        public final int photoId;
        public final String title;
        public final String author;
        public final String content;

        public DummyItem(String id, int photoId, String title, String author, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.photoId = photoId;
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
            this.content = content;
        }
    }
}
```

// List Fragment

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.BitmapImageViewTarget;

import com.app.test.R;
import com.app.test.DummyContent;

/**
 * Shows a list of all available quotes.
 */
public class PortfolioListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private Callback callback = dummyCallback;

    /**
     * A callback interface. Called whenever a item has been selected.
     */
    public interface Callback {
        void onItemSelected(String id);
    }

    /**
     * A dummy no-op implementation of the Callback interface. Only used when no active Activity is present.
     */
    private static final Callback dummyCallback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter());
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // notify callback about the selected list item
        callback.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
    }

    /**
     * onAttach(Context) is not called on pre API 23 versions of Android.
     * onAttach(Activity) is deprecated but still necessary on older devices.
     */
    @TargetApi(23)
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        onAttachToContext(context);
    }

    /**
     * Deprecated on API 23 but still necessary for pre API 23 devices.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            onAttachToContext(activity);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the fragment attaches to the context
     */
    protected void onAttachToContext(Context context) {
        if (!(context instanceof Callback)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement callback interface.");
        }

        callback = (Callback) context;
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return DummyContent.ITEMS.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_article, container, false);
            }

            final DummyContent.DummyItem item = (DummyContent.DummyItem) getItem(position);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.article_title)).setText(item.title);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.article_subtitle)).setText(item.author);
            final ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(item.photoId).asBitmap().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(img) {
                @Override
                protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                    RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getActivity().getResources(), resource);
                    circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                    img.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public PortfolioListFragment() {
    }
}
```

Comment: update your tried code and error what you got after try using string resource?

Comment: I edited to show the resources line i am adding.

Comment: update your error code so we can understand actual problem.

Comment: Error: Non static field 'res' cannot be accessed from a static context. I understand this error but i dont know how to add items from a non static context.

Comment: Why would you do additem class in static class? simple call that method from non-static class. or you can store value to static string then pass it to method.

Comment: I am not trying to do this, this is a stub from the master/detail flow. What i am trying to achieve is use a string resource. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: static String contentA = getResources().getString(R.string.contentA); -- then add -- addItem(new DummyItem("1", R.drawable.p1, "Item #1", "Author A", contentA);

Comment: Non static field 'contentA' cannot be accessed from a static context.

Comment: static String contentA = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.contentA); try this one. (or)  static String contentA = getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.contentA);

Comment: Its not as easy as adding one lines, it does not work. I found a solution that works and have edited the post but there is a memory leak warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check below code . You can pass a Context when Calling this Class from the activity and than you can acess the  String resources .**

```
public class DummyContent {

    /**
     * An array of sample items.
     */
    private  Context context ;
    public DummyContent(Context context){
        this.context = context ;
        addStaticItem(); 
    }

    public static  List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * A map of sample items. Key: sample ID; Value: Item.
     */
    public static  Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<>(5);

     public void addStaticItem(){
         addItem(new DummyItem("1", R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Item #1", "Author A", "Content A"));
         addItem(new DummyItem("2", R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Item #2", "Author B","Content B"));
         addItem(new DummyItem("3", R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Item #3", "Author C", context.getResources().getString(R.string.text_ok) ));
     }



    private void addItem(DummyItem item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }

    public  class DummyItem {
        public  String id;
        public  int photoId;
        public  String title;
        public  String author;
        public  String content;

        public DummyItem(String id, int photoId, String title, String author, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.photoId = photoId;
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
            this.content = content;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is your `PortfolioListFragment` class :

```
public class PortfolioListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private Callback callback = dummyCallback;

    /**
     * A callback interface. Called whenever a item has been selected.
     */
    public interface Callback {
        void onItemSelected(String id);
    }

    /**
     * A dummy no-op implementation of the Callback interface. Only used when no active Activity is present.
     */
    private static final Callback dummyCallback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DummyContent dummyContent = new DummyContent(getContext());
        setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter());
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // notify callback about the selected list item
        callback.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
    }

    /**
     * onAttach(Context) is not called on pre API 23 versions of Android.
     * onAttach(Activity) is deprecated but still necessary on older devices.
     */
    @TargetApi(23)
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        onAttachToContext(context);
    }

    /**
     * Deprecated on API 23 but still necessary for pre API 23 devices.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            onAttachToContext(activity);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the fragment attaches to the context
     */
    protected void onAttachToContext(Context context) {
        if (!(context instanceof Callback)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement callback interface.");
        }

        callback = (Callback) context;
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return DummyContent.ITEMS.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_article, container, false);
            }

            final DummyContent.DummyItem item = (DummyContent.DummyItem) getItem(position);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.article_title)).setText(item.title);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.article_subtitle)).setText(item.author);
            final ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(item.photoId).asBitmap().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(img) {
                @Override
                protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                    RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getActivity().getResources(), resource);
                    circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                    img.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public PortfolioListFragment() {
    }
}
```

Comment: It crashes with your edits

Static member 'com.app.test.DummyContent.context' accessed via instance reference

Also, Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak

Comment: Ok let me try .

Comment: I have put the addItem in a method , You can call it after creating a object of this class . And i don't think the instance shuold need to a static for adding item . Please check .

Comment: Piash, i found a solution that works but there is one line which is similar to what you have shown that throws a memory leak warning. Is that an issue? `private static Context context;`

Comment: No , Calling the context from the static { } field is the issue .  You can use my edited answer . If my answer helps you , Please give up a vote .

Comment: The answer seems fine but it says method addStaticItem not used. I need a solution that adds items to the List<DummyItem> ITEMS. Alternatively, i dont mind rewriting this class to make it non static completely. I just dont know how.

Comment: Check the edited answer. I called the addItemStatic() in constructor . Now your item will be added . 
And one more things you have to clear the concepts of Static , We don't need to add static in all field .

Comment: no errors now, but the page is blank, the list does not show any items.

Comment: notice now,  Why do you using final keyword ? final before any variable mean it declared you can not assign new value to it . Check my edited answer , It will works fine now .

Comment: Ok Please upload the activity or adapter code  , from where you are accessing this values .

Comment: have a look at the list fragment now.

Comment: OK , I found your  bug , let me  fixed it .

Comment: Check the edited answer . And one more thing before accessing DummyContent Class ITEMS & ITEM_MAP  , try to make an object as like : 
DummyContent dummyContent = new DummyContent(context);

Comment: If it's worked , Please give a upvote , that may be helpfull for others

Comment: Oh nice, that seems to works. But it crashes on api 15. i have still accepted it as the answer though since it provides a non static solution.

Comment: Can yo u specify the logcat , Maybe i can help you with the issue .

Comment: `DummyContent dummyContent = new DummyContent(getContext());` the getContext requires > API 23 so it crashes on lower devices.

Comment: When you try to access the the class from the Activity try to use 
new DummyContent(this) ;
From fragment You can pass also new DummyContent(getActivity()) ;

Comment: DummyContent(getActivity()) works nicely and the app is stable with your solution.  I integrated everything but now the list gets items added again and again, probably because of addStaticItem(). I am trying to put a condition to check but cant find it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can't use a `findViewById(R.string.myString)` resource because it isn't final? Not really sure if that's what you are asking or not.

Comment: This is not an activity so findViewById wont be resolved.

Comment: Ah yes. I see that now. In that case, there will need to be a Context that is passed so that you can get the string resources. The answer above mine does a good job at showing this.

Comment: I tried using that but it crashes, I am trying to debug that now. Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference